# Postgresql 9.3 installation fails

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to install postgresql 9.3 in my ubuntu lucid machine. The problem is that I'm getting this error when running apt-get install postgresql-9.3

```
=> apt-get install postgresql-9.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  postgresql-client-9.3
Suggested packages:
  oidentd ident-server locales-all postgresql-doc-9.3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 700 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,944 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ lucid-pgdg/main postgresql-client-9.3 amd64 9.3.2-1.pgdg10.4+1 [2,186 kB]
Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ lucid-pgdg/main postgresql-9.3 amd64 9.3.2-1.pgdg10.4+1 [6,758 kB]
Fetched 8,944 kB in 6s (1,294 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-client-9.3.
(Reading database ... 48797 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking postgresql-client-9.3 (from .../postgresql-client-9.3_9.3.2-1.pgdg10.4+1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-9.3.
Unpacking postgresql-9.3 (from .../postgresql-9.3_9.3.2-1.pgdg10.4+1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-9.3 (9.3.2-1.pgdg10.4+1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative pg_basebackup.1.gz can't be slave of psql.1.gz: it is a slave of postmaster.1.gz
dpkg: error processing postgresql-client-9.3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-9.3:
 postgresql-9.3 depends on postgresql-client-9.3; however:
  Package postgresql-client-9.3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-client-9.3
 postgresql-9.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've been searching on google for two hours without solving the problem. Why is this happening and how could I solve it?

Comment: Do you have a different (older) version of PostgreSQL installed? Remove it first.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to upgrade from 9.1 to 9.3 on a production server. So I was hoping to do some kind of "hot swap" with no downtime.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can I remove my current version using `apt-get remove postgresql-9.1` without losing any data?

Comment: @Oleander There are no database file differences between PG minor versions (eg, 9.1 => 9.3) so you do not need to do a full dump and restore. I would shutdown postgres, take a full backup of the database files (eg, tar czf /backup/pg.tgz /path/to/pgfiles/) then upgrade and restore the backup. You're playing with fire doing this on a production server though. I do not recommend proceeding until you completely understand the process, and have tested it on another box first.

Comment: @fukawi2 9.1 and 9.3 are [**major** versions](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) though, full dump and restore are needed (at least), but maybe `pg_upgrade` could help.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev Ah yes, my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 12):

It seems there was a [bug](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20130508192711.GA9243@msgid.df7cb.de) in the 9.1 packages, but it should be fixed.

As indicated in the linked thread the issue could be resolved by running :

```
update-alternatives --remove postmaster.1.gz /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz
```

and then reinstalling postgresql-9.1:

```
apt-get install -f
apt-get install --reinstall postgresql-9.1
```